# How to reset X back into its original position within the arrays?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crash, maze

I have been making a maze game over the past few weeks and have finished coding it 3 days ago. I have been testing the game for any bugs, and everything seemed alright, however one major problem I have been having is that the game crashes if I am wanting to play the same level in one run of the game. For example, I play level 1 and 2, and if I select either of them again on the main menu, the game gets a blank screen and crashes.
I have sourced the bug into three of my functions, which are the following:

```
void position(int lvl) {
    int x, y;
    if (lvl == 1) {
        x = startingPointX(lvl, y);
        lvl1[x][y] = me;
    }
    if (lvl == 2) {
        x = startingPointX(lvl, y);
        lvl2[x][y] = me;
    }
    if (lvl == 3) {
        x = startingPointX(lvl, y);
        lvl3[x][y] = me;
    }
    if (lvl == 4) {
        x = startingPointX(lvl, y);
        lvl4[x][y] = me;
    }
    if (lvl == 5) {
        x = startingPointX(lvl, y);
        lvl5[x][y] = me;
    }
    if (lvl == 6) {
        x = startingPointX(lvl, y);
        lvl6[x][y] = me;
    }
}
```

Here is the second function:

```
int positionFinder(int lvl, int &y) {
    int xCoord;
    if (lvl == 1) {
        /*This is for level 1*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl1[i][j] == '@') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 2) {
        /*This is for level 2*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl2[i][j] == '@') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 3) {
        /*This is for level 3*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl3[i][j] == '@') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 4) {
        /*This is for the solution of level 1*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl4[i][j] == '@') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 5) {
        /*This is for the solution of level 2*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl5[i][j] == '@') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 6) {
        /*This is for the solution of level 3*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl6[i][j] == '@') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The third function is this:

```
int startingPointX(int lvl, int &y) {
    int xCoord;
    if (lvl == 1) {
        /*This is for level 1*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl1[i][j] == 'X') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 2) {
        /*This is for level 2*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl2[i][j] == 'X') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 3) {
        /*This is for level 3*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl3[i][j] == 'X') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 4) {
        /*This is for the solution of level 1*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl4[i][j] == 'X') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 5) {
        /*This is for the solution of level 2*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl5[i][j] == 'X') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (lvl == 6) {
        /*This is for the solution of level 3*/
        for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
                if (lvl6[i][j] == 'X') {
                    xCoord = i;
                    y = j;
                    return xCoord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for the crash is that when the level runs it searches for X in int startingPointX, however then in void position the game searches for me, which is the '@', therefore if i start the second level, there will be no more 'X' in the level. The function int startingPointX is returning 0 which won't set the y, giving the y a random value. Thus, the line lvl1[x][y]; in void position will make the game will do random things due to y having a random value, which is likely out of range, resulting in a crash.

I have tried quite a few ways to change how the functions work, but every time it still ends up crashing. Help would be appreciated, thanks

Here is the full code to compile and run:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2lLG0MNZMxdT3kteTBtR0puWlE
I used Windows Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with multiple potential solutions you can try implementing:

My first thought was to hardcode the starting position of `me` when each level is called instead of searching for the 'X'. The way you've coded your application, this also requires that when you complete the level, you change the current position of `me` back to a blank space, or there will still be an @ at the end when the level is called again.

Another quick solution would be to store the starting position coordinates and setting that stored coordinate back to 'X' when you complete a level, once again changing the @ back to a blank space.

Have you tried making each level a const character array, and copying them into another char array, such as 'CurrentLevel'?

You can achieve this using `memcpy`, for example:

`const char lvl1[20][20] = (your array);
 char currentLevel[20][20] = {0}; //all initialised to 0`

Later in your code when you want to create the desired level:

`//Copy the contents of lvl1 into currentLevel, up to the size of the array
memcpy(currentLevel, lvl1, sizeof(currentLvel));`

Using this approach, you are able to recreate each level, including the 'X'
You will have to make changes to your code to accommodate this solution, however by referring to currentLevel instead of levels 1 - 6.

Comment: Hi there, I tried using your first idea of hardcoding the starting position of 'me' so it turns into a blank space, but that doesn't seem to load the '@' character in the maze, so im unable to move anything round the maze to reach the end.

Comment: I have also tried using memcpy, but my skill level isn't high enough to apply that into my code even after searching for a good few hours of how to implement it